# If $m$ is a positive integer, show that $(ma, mb) = m(a, b)$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

What I did was let $(a,b)=d$. Then writing the linear combination, $max+mby=md$. Then, to prove that any common divisor of $ma$ and $mb$ can divide $md$. I let $ma={ma_1}{c}$ and $mb={mb_2}{c}$. Then, substituting them into the linear combination, I get ${ma_1}{c}x+{mb_2}cy=md$ which equals to $c({ma_1}x+{mb_2}y)=d$, making $c\mid d$. Is this correct?

Comment: That's a good start, you've shown that it's a common divisor, but you also need to show that it's the *greatest* common divisor.

Comment: How do I show that? Could I show that using the division algorithm?

Comment: What if I now show that $d'=(a,b)$ making $d'$ less than or equal to $d$. Since $d'|a$ and $d'|b$, $d'$ should divide $d$ making $d'$ greater or equal to  $d$ which is a contradiction making $d=(a,b)$.